# Partícula apassivadora com verbos no gerúndio em textos escritos em terceira pessoa

Tags: voz-passiva, gerúndios

Eu já vi estas redações em textos:

"Jogando-se num cassino, arrisca-se perder dinheiro."

"Jogando num cassino, arrisca-se perder dinheiro."

"Introduzindo-se essa notação na equação acima, obtém-se:"

"Introduzindo essa notação na equação acima, obtém-se:

Não consigo encontrar alguma referência que recomende um ou outro, ou explique se há situações em que um seja preferível ao outro. Alguém poderia me orientar?

Comment: É de notar que *se* pode indicar sujeito indeterminado: https://www.infoescola.com/portugues/particula-se/.